# Model-bind interface property with Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a command looking like:

```
public interface ICommand {
    // Just a marker interface
}

public interface IUserAware {
    Guid UserId { get; set; }
}

public class CreateSomething : ICommand, IUserAware
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
}
```

The REST request is:

```
PUT /create HTTP/1.1
UserId: 7da6f9ee-2bfc-70b1-f93c-10c950c8f6b0 // Possible an Auth token and not a userId like here.
Host: localhost:63079
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
{
    "title": "This is a test title"
}
```

I have a API controller action looking:

```
[HttpPut, Route("create")]
public IHttpActionResult CreateSomething([FromBody]CreateSomething command)
{
    // I would like command.UserId already binded here
}
```

The `Title` property on my model is filled out with the body of the request, but I would like to bind the `command.UserId` property using some values from the request headers (e.g. from a authentication token).

**How can I bind the property of `IUserAware` from a request header value, with e.g. a model-binder, without having to create a binder for the concrete class `CreateSomething`?**

I've tried various combinations of the `IModelBinder` interface in Web API, but with no real luck.

It also feels redundant to to use:

```
[HttpPut, Route("create")]
public IHttpActionResult CreateSomething([FromBody]CreateSomething command)
{
    command.UserId = GetUserIdFromTheRequest();
}
```

Or getting the `UserId` from a dependency on the controller and set it like the above.

**How it is done in ASP.NET MVC**

In ASP.NET MVC it is possible to do the following to get it work:

```
public class UserAwareModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, System.Type modelType)
    {
        var baseModel = base.CreateModel(controllerContext, bindingContext, modelType);
        var commandModel = baseModel as IUserAware;
        if (commandModel != null) 
        {
             commandModel.UserId = controllerContext.HttpContext.User; // or get it from the HttpContext headers.
        }

        return baseModel;
    }
}
```

And wire it up at startup with:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new UserAwareModelBinder();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on @Todd last comment, the answer to the question is:

Create a `HttpParameterBinding` class:

```
public class UserAwareHttpParameterBinding : HttpParameterBinding
{
    private readonly HttpParameterBinding _paramaterBinding;
    private readonly HttpParameterDescriptor _httpParameterDescriptor;

    public UserAwareHttpParameterBinding(HttpParameterDescriptor descriptor) : base(descriptor)
    {
        _httpParameterDescriptor = descriptor;
        _paramaterBinding = new FromBodyAttribute().GetBinding(descriptor);
    }

    public override async Task ExecuteBindingAsync(ModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider, HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await _paramaterBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync(metadataProvider, actionContext, cancellationToken);

        var baseModel = actionContext.ActionArguments[_httpParameterDescriptor.ParameterName] as IUserAware;
        if (baseModel != null)
        {
            baseModel.UserId = new Guid("6ed85eb7-e55b-4049-a5de-d977003e020f"); // Or get it form the actionContext.RequestContext!
        }
    }
}
```

And wire it up in the `HttpConfiguration`:

```
configuration.ParameterBindingRules.Insert(0, descriptor => typeof(IUserAware).IsAssignableFrom(descriptor.ParameterType) ? new UserAwareHttpParameterBinding(descriptor) : null);
```

> If anyone know how this is done in .NET Core MVC - please edit this
>   post or comment.

Answer (score 5):

```
public class CreateSomethingModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        string key = bindingContext.ModelName;
        ValueProviderResult val = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(key);
        if (val != null)
        {
            string s = val.AttemptedValue as string;
            if (s != null)
            {
                return new CreateSomething(){Title = s; UserId = new Guid(ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["userId"]);}
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

and add attribute on the type declaration

```
[ModelBinder(typeof(CreateSomethingModelBinder))]
public class CreateSomething  { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, is possible to create a more generic way of handling this? I would like to avoid manually binding other properties - I only want to bind properties based on the interface - others should be binding as normal.

Comment: ModelBinder is for binding to specific custom objects.For user authentication you should implement web api security read more on [link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api)  and use HttpContext.Current.User or create base controller where you can implement CurrentUser and separate the user from the model binding process.

Comment: The need is not only for authentication, but a general question on how to bind custom properties in WebAPI. I've updated my question on how to do this in MVC, I just dont know how to do it in WebAPI alone.

Comment: The binding of custom properties in MVC is like you write it:
  `public IHttpActionResult CreateSomething([FromBody]CreateSomething command)`
  but you can't expect MVC to guess from where to get the values for your object. In you case you should pass userId in the body with the title.

Comment: No, it is not. DefaultModelBinder with the overriding of the `BindModel` is MVC namespace thing:  System.Web.Mvc.

Comment: Well I think you can use `TypeConverter` for that job

Comment: Hi Todd, seems like the method is not compiling - there is no method signature with the use of `ConvertFrom` with `Type destinationType`. Also it seem not possible to get the HttpRequest from here. :-)

Comment: Sorry I was taken the params from ConvertTo method, but anyway it doesn't work too(I tested it), so I am deleting it from the answer. Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20855185/webapi2-custom-parameter-binding-to-bind-partial-parameters) for implementation with `HttpParameterBinding` or write your own custom [media formatter](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/media-formatters)