# ASP.NET Core MVC - Bind model containing property that uses an interface

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.1

I have a model that contains an interface based property, which the concrete implementation being discoverable via another property of the model.

```
public class SubscriptionViewModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public SubscriptionTypeEnum SubscriptionType { get; set; } // <- Determines the concrete class
    public ISubscriptionCriteria SubscriptionCriteria { get; set; } //<- Property based on interface class
    ...
}
```

When the interface based property is present the model in the controller comes through as null. If removed, everything binds as expected.

```
[HttpPost("api/[controller]/[action]")]
public async Task Post([FromBody]SubscriptionViewModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

This will be because the controller doesn't know which solid implementation to use for the interface.

Any ideas how I can solve this? It looks like this might be achievable using a custom `IModelBinderProvider` or `BindingBehaviorAttribute`?

I guess I could have a `SuperSubscriptionCriteria` implementation that contains all possible properties used by concrete implementations of `ISubscriptionCriteria` and then rely on AutoMapper to convert them to the real implementations. But this seems like a hack and would require on-going maintenance as new `ISubscriptionCriteria` implementations are added.

Comment: What is the purpose of having `ISubscriptionCriteria` as property in ViewModel? I'm just curious.

Comment: Depending upon the type of subscription there's several different criteria types available, specific to certain subscriptions. In this case subscriptions are email alerts about permit data - www.permitwatch.co.nz

Comment: How does actual implementation get assign to `ISubscriptionCriteria`? Normally, ***MVC***'s ViewMode doesn't have external dependencies, unless you are using it as ***MVVM***'s View Model.

Comment: AutoMapper is used to populate the ViewModel from other classes, one of my previous q's might give more detail - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38953348